# RoslynTargetsPath appears to be not set for VisualStudio

Tags: unity-game-engine, mono, visual-studio-mac

Today (without me initiating any updates) VisualStudio (VisualStudio for Mac Community Version 8.0.6 build 4) all of a sudden kept telling me I needed to upgrade Mono (I'm on a Mac). I did so. After that none of my projects would compile because it seems the configuration is messed up and I think RoslynTargetsPath is not set. I'm using VisualStudio with Unity if that makes any difference.

The first error I got was this

> "~/Library/Caches/VisualStudio/8.0/MSBuild/17745_1//Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets
>   was not found"

Looking at the file system I saw that the file was in the Rosyln subfolder. So I edited my Assembly-CSharp.csproj file and changed the import definition from

```
 <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)/Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets" />
```

to

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)/Roslyn/Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets" />
```

Once I did this the error changed to

> "The target "Build" does not exist in the project. (MSB4057)"

I researched that and tried adding this to the project file

The error went back to this

> "~/Library/Caches/VisualStudio/8.0/MSBuild/17745_1//Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets
>   was not found".

Notice the "//" in the path. I checked my MSBuild.dll.config and the definition for RoslynTargetsPath is this

```
<property name="RoslynTargetsPath" value="$([MSBuild]::GetToolsDirectory32())\Roslyn" />
```

So then I changed the import in my project file to this

```
<Import Project="$(RoslynTargetsPath)/Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets" />
```

And the error changed to

> "/Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets was not found".

So it looks like RoslynTargetsPath is an empty string. I don't know why I was forced to upgrade Mono when VisualStudio had not been updated.

Comment: This problem was fixed by upgrading to the latest version of Mono released today (5/17/2019)